# Why I get two http:// when I send mail by using delayed_job

Tags: ruby, http, delayed-job

```
require 'digest'
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def receive_compliment(compliment)
    @recipients  = "#{compliment.receiver.email}"
    @from        = SERVICE_EMAIL
    @subject     = "Nouveau compliment de #{compliment.user.to_str}"
    @sent_on     = Time.now
    @compliment  = compliment    
    @content_type = "text/plain"
    @body[:url] =  user_compliments_url(@compliment.receiver)
    @body[:root_url] = root_url(:host)      
  end

end
```

Hi, guys.

As you see above. this is the code sending mail.
 I use `UserMaililer.send_later("deliver_receive_complimen",compliment)` to send mail.
and the mail sent, however, when I open the mail, I got something like this:

```
Bonjour Kamil ,

 vous a envoyé un compliment sur Blanee!

Cliquez ici pour afficher l’expéditeur et ses commentaires sur vous :
http://http://feature.blanee.net/membres/compliments/66

Merci,
L'équipe Blanee
________________
Ce mail est à l'attention de Kamil  B..
Vous voulez contrôler les notifications que vous recevez? Veuillez vous rendre sur : http://http://feature.blanee.net/mon-compte/notifications.
Vous ne vous êtes pas inscrit sur Blanee et vous avez reçu ce mail? Veuillez le signaler en envoyant un email à l'adresse suivante : admin@blanee.net
```

As you see above . there are two http://, anybody help? I tested . if I send mail directly, then there is only one http://, but when I sent it by delayed_job then it shows two http:///

my ERB template file:

```
Bonjour <%="#{@compliment.receiver.first_name.to_s.strip},"%>

<%=h(@compliment.user.to_str)%> vous a envoyé un compliment sur Blanee!

Cliquez ici pour afficher l’expéditeur et ses commentaires sur vous :
<%=@url%>

Merci,
L'équipe Blanee
________________
Ce mail est à l'attention de <%=@compliment.receiver.email%>.
Vous voulez contrôler les notifications que vous recevez? Veuillez vous rendre sur : <%=@root_url%>mon-compte/notifications.
Vous ne vous êtes pas inscrit sur Blanee et vous avez reçu ce mail? Veuillez le signaler en envoyant un email à l'adresse suivante : admin@blanee.net
```

and in fact, I tried wrote the *_url in the template file. but it still bug when sent from delayed_job.

Comment: here is my erb template file.

Comment: Where is `@url` coming from? Why not use ` @body[:url]` ?

Comment: they are the same, I tried . don't work too. now I think the issue is not cause by mail sending. but a bug when generating restful url in  delayed_job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using restful URLs with Action Mailer, you should generate the url with a `:host` parameter inside the mailer. Does the following work for you?

```
Cliquez ici pour afficher l’expéditeur et ses commentaires sur vous :
<%= user_compliments_url(@compliment.receiver, :host => 'feature.blanee.net') %>
```

Be sure to leave the `http://` off the `:host`.